# java.lang.AbstractMethodError when updating to play framework 2.7.3

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to update play framework for one of our services from 2.6.x to 2.7.3. After that some of the unit tests are failing with this error:

```
[info]   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.api.i18n.Messages$MessagesParser.scala$util$parsing$combinator$Parsers$$lastNoSuccessVar()Lscala/util/DynamicVariable;
[info]   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:881)
[info]   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:237)
[info]   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:237)
[info]   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:217)
[info]   at play.api.i18n.Messages$MessagesParser.parse(Messages.scala:185)
[info]   at play.api.i18n.Messages$.parse(Messages.scala:116)
[info]   at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApiProvider$$anonfun$loadMessages$2.apply(Messages.scala:614)
[info]   at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApiProvider$$anonfun$loadMessages$2.apply(Messages.scala:613)
[info]   at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
[info]   at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApiProvider.loadMessages(Messages.scala:613)
[info]   ...
```

I could not figure out why. The only code in the stack trace that belongs to us is this line:

```
  val injector = GuiceApplicationBuilder().injector()
  val controller = injector.instanceOf[TestController] // this line is in stack trace

  class TestController @Inject () (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc)
    with RealController {
    ...
  }
```

The controller code doesn't matter here because it's failing for all controllers that follow this pattern.

I suspect this is compatibility issue with other libraries so I tried to update versions for other libs, but no luck so far. Some related versions:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
sbt.version=1.2.8
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.6.0" % Test,
"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.9" % Test,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.23" % Test,
"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "4.0.3" % Test
```

I checked the play 2.7 migration guide but couldn't find anything related. I even tried to update to other versions, like 2.7.2, which doesn't have this issue, so it seems some breaking changes in 2.7.3

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 2.11? That went EOL years back. You should definitely plan to upgrade. Not that it is the cause here

Comment: Have you tried 2.7.9 play? If there is a regression, might have been solved in 2.7.9

Comment: I did try 2.7.9, and that didn't work either. I'm guessing this is not a regression since many others use 2.7.3. Maybe it's just my setup

Comment: Another problem might be with `scalatestplus-play`. Check with the following sbt plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph  - maybe this library has a transitive dependency on older Play, which causes this error.

Comment: unfortunately scalatestplus-play 4.0.3 is the last version that supports scala 2.11.

Comment: well I updated scala to 2.12 and that seems resolved this issue. Now I have more other breaking changes...

Comment: @user15155830, please connsider deleting this question, as it probably won't be helpful for others.